# Is there a way to configure Gradle plugin to execute task with build?

Tags: gradle, plugins, build.gradle

I apply my custom plugin to project:

```
plugins {
   id 'my.plugin.gradle-plugin' version '1.0.0'
}
```

This plugin contains task `runMe` and I want to always execute it only with `build` task.

The way to get it specifying in my root project:

```
build.dependsOn runMe
```

But I want to get this behavior by setting up the plugin once and don't repeat this every project which uses the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to check in `apply` method if `build` task already exists. If so you can define a dependency there. Otherwise it's impossible.

Also, where does the `build` task come from? Another plugin? If so apply this plugin in you plugin and then define the dependency.